# Sudo commands allowed in sudoers.d not working

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I have a BBS running on a limited non-root user account on my Debian 9 system. For the most part, this runs great. Occasionally, commands that require root access are run and so I've been using sudo in combination with the sudoers file and the sudoers.d directory to make this all work.

Until now, it has been working without a hitch.

However, now am I getting this issue when the user `com` runs a specific block of code:

```
[sudo] password for com:
Sorry, user com is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/last' as root on [redacted].
Matching Defaults entries for com on [hostname]:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User com may run the following commands on [hostname]:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/curl
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/last

Press ENTER to return:
```

The actual code that generates the above in a bash script:

```
    recent=`sudo /usr/bin/last | grep "com"`
    r=`sudo -l`
    printf '%s\n' "$r"
    printf '%s\n' "$recent"
    read -n 1 -r -p "Press ENTER to return: "
```

Yes, I also tried the command without the grep part.

Previously I was just using `sudo last`, but changing it to `sudo /usr/bin/last` did not make it work either.

The other entries in the sudoers.d directory (the other two above last you can see) took effect immediately without issue as soon as the user `com` logged in again.

If I add the following to the sudoers.d directory, it *does* work:

```
com ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, I don't want to just allow everything in the sudoers.d directory as that's not a real solution but a hacky workaround. If there's a security hole somewhere, this could then be exploited, and not using the above line reduces the attack surface. Does anyone know why sudoers.d is failing to cause the last command - and only the last command - to work?

It occured to me possibly that `last` is using some other process or file to which perhaps only root/admin users would have access. However, that doesn't appear to be the case as **wtmp**, the file used by `last` has a **664** permission, with ["Read" permissions for everyone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335904/why-var-log-wtmp-and-var-log-lastlog-have-read-permission-for-other-users-is/335923).

Comment: Did you check the permissions on /usr/bin/last?

Comment: @Roadowl Yup, as I stated in my update it has a permission of 664. I was able to get it to work finally but removing the "sudo", not sure why that didn't work the first time. I don't personally have an issue now, but the problem is legit as I see no reason why one could not execute that as sudo, as I have all the proper configs to do that.

Comment: If `/usr/bin/last` has a permission of 664 it cannot run as an executable as such.